# How to write the output of system command in another file in perl?

Tags: perl

I am trying to run a `system` command in perl. And I want the output of the command into another file. I am trying to run the below code but I am not able to get the result in `result_file`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Cwd;

my $path=getcwd();
my $result_file="$path/Something.txt";
open (LOG, ">$result_file") || die "Cannot create file - $!\n";
print "Executing File.\n";
system("dmexpress /run $DTL_file > $result_file") ;
close(LOG);
```

Comment: So close to a good error message!  please include $result_file in the text.  (or just use autodie)

Comment: What is `$DTL_file`? Also, you must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program you write.

Comment: $DTL_file is a file with some code which I want to run with system command. It is giving some errors but those errors are printing on screen not in the specified `result_file`.

Answer (score 0):

Done with a small change!

1. No need to open file before `system` command. As suggested by @toolic.
2. Use `2>&1` in `system` command to capture the errors in file(if any).

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/perl
   use strict;
   use warnings;
   use Cwd;

   my $path=getcwd();
   my $result_file="$path/Something.txt";
   #open (LOG, ">$result_file") || die "Cannot create file - $!\n";
   print "Executing File.\n";
   system("dmexpress /run $DTL_file > $result_file 2>&1") ;
   #close(LOG);
   ```

Answer (score -1):

You can capture the output with backticks then print that to a file:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $result_file="Something.txt";
open (LOG, ">", $result_file) || die "Cannot create file - $!\n";
print "Executing File.\n";
my $res = `dmexpress /run $DTL_file`;
print LOG $res;
close(LOG);
```